# When to use Task.Run

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to have a background process (console application) that reads a message queue indefinitely.

Would this be the proper use of `Task.Run`?

```
do
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var client = new QueueMessageClient())
        {
            var result = client.GetMessages();

            // Do something with the resulting messages
            Parallel.ForEach(result.Messages, message =>
            {

            });
        }
    });
} while (true);
```

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I want to spin off a `Task` for each run on the queue.

Comment: see [this walkthrough](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) for a good overview of Task.Run. I second the answer below though, you've got your loops inverted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but the loop should probably be inside the lambda (and inside the `using` block), not around it... otherwise you'll have thousands of threads reading the message queue.

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (var client = new QueueMessageClient())
    {
        do
        {
            var result = client.GetMessages();

            // Do something with the resulting messages
            Parallel.ForEach(result.Messages, message =>
            {

            });
        } while (true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to have each message from the queue fire on a task, background thread, to process the message which means going to a db, storage system, etc.

Comment: @Sam, in this case, just use Task.Run for each of the messages in `result`

Comment: But are you sure you want to process them in parallel? Shouldn't you wait until you're done processing a message before you start processing the next one?

Comment: I am processing a AWS SQS Queue. So what happens is a message is dumped in the queue. I want this background process to read 10 messages at a time and then fire off a task for each to go do work. I do not have to wait for it at all.

Comment: In this case, just fire a new task with Task.Run for each message you receive. Parallel.ForEach doesn't guarantee that each message will be processed in a different thread (by default it uses as many threads as there are CPU cores, IIRC)